# Material design for web - how to make an autocomplete input

Tags: html, material-design

I am using google's [material design for web](https://material.io/develop/web/components). And I would like to use their [select component](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/select-menus/) as an autocomplete component. What I am aiming for is the [autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) you can see in react mui. I have removed the `disabled` and `readonly` input attributes but I still can't write anything to input field.

```
<div class="mdc-select demo-width-class">
  <div class="mdc-select__anchor">
    <span class="mdc-select__ripple"></span>
    <input type="text" class="mdc-select__selected-text">
    <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
    <span class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
    <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
    <ul class="mdc-list">
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" data-value="" aria-selected="true"></li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="grains">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="vegetables">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Vegetables
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="fruit">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Fruit
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I enable the input field for writing into it, so that I can adapt and make an autocomplete input field?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox that replicates your problem?

Comment: The component you are asking for built using react mui, is what you are looking for is an answer without using react?

Comment: @Ma'mounothman the component built using react mui is what I am looking for. I would like to get that without using react, yes.

Comment: @Leff what are you still missing in these answers?

Answer (score 2):

since you have mentioned that you would like to see an answer without using react, thus in plain javascript. I have managed to do just that. I have combined the css and markup from `@Sifat Haque`'s answer and the full working autocomplete logic from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp). Though this may seem simple, it was quite a hassle to make this work.

```js
const select = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
   var currentFocus;
 
  inp.addEventListener("input", autocomp);
  inp.addEventListener("click", autocomp);

  inp.addEventListener("focus", autocomp);

  function autocomp(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    closeAllLists();
    currentFocus = -1;

    a = document.createElement("ul");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items mdc-list");

    document.getElementById("autocomp").appendChild(a);

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase() || (val.trim()).length == 0) {
        b = document.createElement("li");
        b.setAttribute("class", "mdc-list-item")
        b.innerHTML = "<span class='mdc-list-item__text'>" + arr[i] + "</span>";
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  }
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("li");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("mdc-list-item--selected");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
      x[i].classList.remove("mdc-list-item--selected");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

}

/*An array containing all the foods :*/
var foods = ["fruit", "vegetables", "grains", "fries"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the foods array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("name-input"), foods);

function makeActive(element) {
  document.getElementById("name-input").focus();
  element.classList.add("mdc-select--focused");
  element.classList.add("mdc-select--activated")
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
}

input[type=text]:active {
  border: none;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  /*overflow-y: scroll; */
}

.autocomplete-items li {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.mdc-select__menu {
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>


    <h2>Autocomplete</h2>

    <p>Start typing:</p>

    <!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->

    <form autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">

      <div class="mdc-select" onclick="makeActive(this)">
        <div class="mdc-select__anchor demo-width-class">
          <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
          <div class="mdc-select__selected-text"></div>
          <span class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
          <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
          <input type="text" id="name-input" name="selectione">


        </div>
        <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface">
          <div class="autocomplete" id='autocomp' style="width:200px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Hope this helps!

edit: added standard selection option

Answer (score 1):

I've created a demo and it somewhat does what you want. The two issues it has are-

1. User has to click twice(double click) to input values(I can't to make it work on a single click)
2. The position of the `label` overlaps the selected value(Even after giving another class or styling it dynamically)

> **If anybody has any idea about how to go through these issues, their ideas are
>   welcome.**
>  @Leff, you yourself look like a person with experience, can
>   you solve them? If yes, please do so and please also enlighten us(me).

Also, **I've used `jquery` in this code** if you're looking for only `vanilla javascript`, you might have to do it yourself or find a person who can as I'm no expert in that area but that's the logical part. Your main problem seemed to be of `HTML` which should be resolved.

Below is the demo, see if it helps you.

```js
// initialize
const select = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));

// stop the original propagation so that input field remains editable
$('#food').on('click', (event) => {
  return false;
});

// Demo Data
const foodArr = ['Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta', 'Vegetables', 'Fruit'];

// You'll have to use ajax here to get the data
$('#food').on('keyup', (event) => {

  //console.clear();
  let $this = $(event.currentTarget);
  let currValue = $this.val();

  let search = new RegExp(currValue, 'i'); // prepare a regex object // Your custom condition

  let matchArr = foodArr.filter(item => search.test(item)); //store the result in an array
  let $select = "";

  // check if array is empty
  if (matchArr.length > 0) {

    // map the elements of the array and create option html
    matchArr.forEach((item) => {

      $select += `<li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="${item}"> ${item}</li>`;

    })

  } else { // if array is empty, display no match

    $select += `<li class="mdc-list-item" id="no_match"> No match found!</li>`;

  }
  //console.log(matchArr);

  // if the data was selected before, unselect it
  $('.mdc-list-item--selected:first').attr({'data-value': ''});
  $('.mdc-list-item--selected:first').text('');
  $('.mdc-list-item--selected:not(:first)').removeClass('mdc-list-item--selected');

  // remove all previous option elements
  $('.mdc-list-item:not(.mdc-list-item--selected:first)').remove();

  // add new option elements
  $('.mdc-list-item--selected').after($select);

  // start the click function, so that dropdown doesn't close
  $this.click();
});

// When any option is selected, show it on input field
$(document).on('click', '.mdc-list-item:not(#no_match)', (event) => {
  
  let $this = $(event.currentTarget);
  $this.addClass('mdc-list-item--selected');
  
  $('.mdc-floating-label').addClass('mdc-floating-label--float-above');
  
  $('.mdc-select__anchor').addClass('demo-width-class mdc-ripple-upgraded')
  $('.mdc-line-ripple').addClass('mdc-line-ripple--active mdc-line-ripple--deactivating')
  $('.mdc-line-ripple').css({'transform-origin': '182px center'})
  
  $('#food').val($this.attr('data-value'));
  // return false;
  // event.stopImmediatePropagation()
});

// if clicked on no match, value of input field should be empty, alternatively you can also make option disabled
$(document).on('click', '#no_match', (event) => {
  
  $('#food').val('');
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>@sauhardnc</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdc-select">
    <div class="mdc-select__anchor demo-width-class" style="width: 100%">
      <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" class="mdc-select__selected-text" id="food"></input>
      <!-- Give a unique id -->
      <!--<div contenteditable="true" class="mdc-select__selected-text" id="fruit"></div>-->
      <span class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
      <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface demo-width-class" style="width: 100%">
      <ul class="mdc-list">
        <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" data-value="" aria-selected="true"></li>
        <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta">
          Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
        </li>
        <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="Vegetables">
          Vegetables
        </li>
        <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="Fruit">
          Fruit
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers here, I created my own function. Also the Material Design for Web Versions in the answers are quite old. Hope this helps for those looking for something like this.

At first, instead of using MDCSelect, I used MDCTextField and MDCMenu components. I thought everything would be easier this way. It took some time though, but I'm done.

The function that triggers the Menu to open when clicking on the TextField may seem a bit weird. @Zachary Haber explains this,

> It appears that the inconsistency is due to a race condition. Clicking
> on the menu causes the focus to leave the input which causes the menu
> to close. And the menu closing causes focus to move back to the input
> making it open again.
>
> The issue is that the menu often closes before the menu has a chance
> to send out the selected event.

To review the original answer for MDCMenu click issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61965646/5698079

Here is a working example;

```js
const textFields = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field');
textFields.forEach(field => {
  mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(field);
});
const menuS = document.querySelector("#menu");
const menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuS);
const searchFieldS = document.querySelector("#food");
menu.setAnchorCorner(mdc.menuSurface.Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT);

document.querySelectorAll('#menu li').forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const selectedLi = this.getAttribute("data-value");
    if (selectedLi != "notfound") {
      // If you are going to post the text field data, I recommend you to get data-value.
      searchFieldS.value = selectedLi;
      searchFieldS.setAttribute("data-value", selectedLi);
    }
  });
});

// Open the menu when text field is focused. 
(function() {
  let menuFocused = false;
  searchFieldS.addEventListener("focusin", () => {
    if (!menuFocused) menu.open = true;
  });
  searchFieldS.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.open = true;
  });

  menuS.addEventListener("focusin", () => {
    menuFocused = true;
  });
  menuS.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
    // This interval is to help make sure that input.focusIn doesn't re-open the menu
    setTimeout(() => {
      menuFocused = false;
    }, 0);
  });
  searchFieldS.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!menuFocused) menu.open = false;
    }, 0);
  });
})();
searchFieldS.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  const keyT = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  const menuList = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-deprecated-list > li > .mdc-deprecated-list-item__text');
  const menuLiss = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-deprecated-list-item');
  const noDataEl = document.querySelector("#menuNoData");

  // 
  const arr = [];
  menuList.forEach(function(searchItem) {
    if (searchItem.parentElement.getAttribute('id') != "menuNoData") {
      searchItem.parentElement.dataset.isfound = searchItem.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(keyT) ? "true" : "false";
      arr.push(searchItem.parentElement.getAttribute("data-isfound"));
    }
  });
  if (arr.filter(function(countArr) {
      return countArr == "true"
    }).length == 0) {
    noDataEl.classList.remove("hide-none");
  } else {
    if (!noDataEl.classList.contains("hide-none")) {
      noDataEl.classList.add("hide-none");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li[data-isfound="false"] {
  display: none;
}

.hide-none {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="mdc-menu-surface--anchor">
  <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="my-label-id">Select a fruit..</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
        </span>
        <input id="food" type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="my-label-id">
    </label>
  <div id="menu" class="mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
    <ul class="mdc-deprecated-list" role="listbox" aria-label="Food picker listbox">
      <li id="menuNoData" class="mdc-deprecated-list-item mdc-deprecated-list-item--disabled hide-none" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true" data-value="notfound" role="option" value="" data-value="">
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__text">No data found.</span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-deprecated-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="grains" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__text">Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta</span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-deprecated-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="vegetables" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__text">Vegetables</span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-deprecated-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="fruit" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-deprecated-list-item__text">Fruit</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/lastofdead/pen/bGMZPzO

Comment: Well, its working in a root. but when create a form i got:
jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: mdc-menu-surface class required in root element.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the input fields along with the select to get an input field and then write some javascript to get the autocomplete functionality. You can check my solution.

```js
console.clear();
const select = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));

select.listen('MDCSelect:change', () => {
  alert(`Selected option at index ${select.selectedIndex} with value "${select.value}"`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mdc-select">
  <div class="mdc-select__anchor demo-width-class">
    <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
    <div class="mdc-select__selected-text"></div>
    <span class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
    <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface demo-width-class">
    <ul class="mdc-list">
      <input type="text" class="mdc-list-item--selected mdc-text-field__input" id="name-input">
      <label for="name-input" class="mdc-floating-label">search....</label>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="grains">
        Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="vegetables">
        Vegetables
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="fruit">
        Fruit
      </li>
      
      <input type="hidden" name="input_name" value="input_value" class="my_mdc-select__value" />
    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, that just puts input below select field, and doesn't make select field a text input

Comment: any demo of what you are looking for?

Comment: this what I am aiming for: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could able to achieve, hope this helps in your implementation. I have not completely implemented the filter logic and all but was able to enter input and display the dropdown simultaneously.

```js
const menuElement = document.querySelector(".mdc-menu");
// const menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuElement);

const inputLabel = document.querySelector(".mdc-text-field");
const inputElem = inputLabel.querySelector("input");
const dropdownIcon = document.querySelector(".mdc-select__dropdown-icon");
let isMenuOpen = false;

inputLabel.addEventListener("click", () => {
  inputElem.focus();
  // menu.open = true;
  if (!isMenuOpen) {
    menuElement.classList.remove("list-menu-close");
    menuElement.classList.add("list-menu-open");
    dropdownIcon.classList.add("dropdown-icon-up");
  } else {
    menuElement.classList.remove("list-menu-open");
    menuElement.classList.add("list-menu-close");
    dropdownIcon.classList.remove("dropdown-icon-up");
  }
  isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
});

inputElem.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  menuElement.classList.remove("list-menu-open");
  menuElement.classList.add("list-menu-close");
  dropdownIcon.classList.remove("dropdown-icon-up");
  isMenuOpen = false;
});
```

```
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--filled">
        <span class="mdc-text-field__ripple"></span>
        <input
          class="mdc-text-field__input"
          type="text"
          aria-labelledby="my-label-id"
        />
        <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
      </label>
      <div>
        <div class="mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface list-menu">
          <ul
            class="mdc-list"
            role="menu"
            aria-hidden="true"
            aria-orientation="vertical"
            tabindex="-1"
          >
            <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem">
              <span class="mdc-list-item__text">A Menu Item</span>
            </li>
            <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem">
              <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Another Menu Item</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
}

.list-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

.list-menu-open {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-menu-close {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.dropdown-icon-up {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-5px);
}
```